# C or C++ sprintf and value in struct

Tags: c, printf

**code:**

```
sprintf(tmp, "xbitmap_width %d\n", symbol->scale);
```

**Output:**

```
xbitmap_width 1075052544
```

**expected output - value of scale which is 5 so it should be:**

```
xbitmap_width 5
```

What am i missing??? Why is `sprintf` taking pointer value?

Comment: try printing `symbol->scale` just before this line

Comment: What type is scale...

Comment: sounds like scale is a pointer

Comment: `sprintf` is dangerous (possible buffer overflow) and is becoming obsolete. Use `snprintf` (or `asprintf`) instead! And show how is `tmp` declared and initialized. Also, show the declaration (and the type) of `symbol`

Comment: i have a struct symbol{int scale;} and struct is initialized with new or malloc so i have a pointer to symbol containing scale.

Comment: i can do int tmpscale = symbol->scale and tmpscale will contain 5

Comment: @Lonko: is the `sprintf` call in the same function/scope as the one that declares/initializes `symbol`?

Comment: Guys thank you for all the help but I found the problem :/ one of the source files was not updated on the build machine and result was that scale as is was left FLOAT not INT as it should be! So I was checking the source that was not actually in the build :( sorry for the confusion!!! i was confused also ... was going insane :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:*
If `symbol->scale` is indeed not a pointer, then also ensure `tmp` is big enough, to avoid overflow. I hope `tmp` is *at least* 18 chars big, but best make it big enough (like 30 or bigger), and if it's allocated on the heap: initialize it to zeroes: `memset` or `calloc(30, sizeof *tmp)` would be preferable.

You may also want to ensure that `symbol` is not a stack value, returned by a function. This, too, would be undefined behaviour. However, given that you say you're using `new` or `malloc` (which _does not initialize the struct, BTW), that can't be the issue.
The not-initializing bit here (when using `malloc`) might be, though: `malloc` merely reserves enough memory to store a given object one or more times. The memory is *not* initialized, though:

```
char *str = malloc(100);
```

Is something like that thing where you give a bunch of monkeys type-writers: eventually one of them might wind up punching in a line of Shakespeare: well, if you `malloc` strings like this, and print them, eventually one of them might end up containing the string *"Don't panic"*.
Now, this isn't *exactly* true, but you get the point...
To ensure your struct is initialized, either use `calloc` or `memset` those members that str giving you grief.

if your struct looks like this:

```
struct symbol
{
    int *scale;
}
```

Then you are passing *the value* of `scale` to `sprintf`. This value is a memory address, not an int. An int, as you may no is guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes in size (most commonly it's 4 though). A pointer is 4 or 8 bytes in size, so passing a pointer, and have `sprintf` interpret it as an `int`, you get undefined behaviour.

To print `5` in your case:

```
struct symbol *symbol = malloc(sizeof *symbol);
int s = 5;
symbol->scale = &s;
printf("%d\n", *(symbol->scale));//dereference the scale pointer
```

But this is undefined behaviour:

```
printf("%d\n", symbol->scale);//passing pointer VALUE ==> memory address
//for completeness & good practices' sake:
free(symbol);
```

Oh, and as stated in the comments: `snprintf` is to `sprintf` what `strncpy` is to `strcpy` and `strncat` is to `strcat`: it's safer to use the function which allows you to specify a maximum of chars to set

Comment: nb - because of order of operations `*symbol->scale` works just fine and is typically how C code is written.

Comment: @Hogan: I know, I tend to over-use parentheses... blame it on my dabbling with scheme in my spare time, but I find it helps readability :P